# Symfony2 slow RouterListener or Firewall

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2

Our new Symfony2 application is running awfully slow in PRODUCTION. It's hosted on an m3.large EC2 instance.

I checked the profiler and the slowest part is either the routerlistener or the firewall http component. On first page load, the routerlistener chokes up and then on succeeding requests the Firewall components causes the hold up.

This happens to this application may be once a week and then just fixes itself which is really strange.

I've attached the profiler images below:
[image]
[image]

What I've tried so far:

1. Disable xdebug
2. Set realpath_cache_size to 4096K
3. Set realpath_cache_ttl to 7200

No shake. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Improved performance considerably simply by using APC.

I was trying to look for a proper fix for this in the application code since I was thinking that using caching is only a band-aid solution. I guess Symfony2 without any caching (APC/Memcache/Varnish/etc) in production  is simply destined to fail.